# Rearranging A Double Summation

Tags: summation

I have the following:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^i a_i {i \choose k} (-b)^{i-k} x^k$$

I want to find a way to express $x^k$ in terms of the outer summation so it would be $x^i$. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is that what you mean? $$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^i a_i {i \choose k} (-b)^{i-k} x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=k}^n a_i {i \choose k} (-b)^{i-k} x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^n x^k \sum_{i=k}^n a_i {i \choose k} (-b)^{i-k}
$$

Comment: Ya, this is exactly what I needed. Could you explain why you can do $\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=k}^n$

Comment: Rewrite the first double sum $$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbf{1}_{k\leq i} [...]$$ are you OK with this step? If so, then you can switch the summations:$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbf{1}_{k\leq i} [...]$$ and /then/ finally get $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=k}^n [...]$$ (where I write "[...]" for the actual summands, that I'm too lazy to type in the comment). I write $\mathbf{1}_A$ for the indicator of $A$, i.e. the function that is $1$ if $A$ is satisfied, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest one can get, is by simplyfying the inner summation.
Rearranging like this,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k} (-b)^{i-k} x^k$$
Then using the binomial theroem, we can get
$$\sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k} (-b)^{i-k} x^k = (x-b)^{i}$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (x-b)^{i}$$
Since we have no other information on $a_i$ we can not further manipulate this expression to yield a "nicer" form.

Comment: I was actually working backwards from $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i (x-b)^{i}$ trying to express it as something like $\sum_{i=0}^n c x^i$ so I would need to find a c